# Sony Xperia Z3 - Lollipop - Signal bar disappeared, no SIM would work

Tags: sony-xperia, sim-card, network-signal, sony-xperia-z3

I'm experiencing problems with my 2 yo Sony Xperia Z3. Today i've changed the SIM card from polish T-Mobile to Orange (I've been using Orange for alot of time, even this particular SIM, and 1 month ago have unlocked the network to use T-mobile) and now it seems like none of the cards would work.

After turning the mobile on there's no SIM pin typebox and the network stays at NO SIGNAL (grey bars with an X on them)

What I've tried:
- rebooting (changes nothing at all),
- different SIM card (still this same happens),
- turning plane mode on (would make the signal bar disappear totally after trying to turn it off)

Any clues?

Comment: When you try making a call, does it try, or does it just say emergency calls only?

Comment: @Abochur actually i found out that my IMEI is wiped (empty space where it's supposed to be after *#06#), guess my baseband/modem is gone, probably wouldn't manage to make it work as i have not made any TWRP backups of system

Comment: Try flashing firmware, this should fix the IMEI. If not, you'll need special tools to repair the IMEI.